# jQuery timer - idle timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, idle-timer

I am trying to implement [Eric Hynds' jquery-idle-timeout](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout) dialog which works fine without any issues. But how can I *timer / idle timeout* to get work even during **computer sleep** or **phone screen-off**.

Currently timer getting paused if computer sleeps or phone screen-off.

Do I need to add any specific jquery events apart from `mousemove keydown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel mousedown`?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the dialog box when the computer sleeps but you can check for the interval when computer wakes up something like this

```
var oldTime = Date.now();

var expire = 50000; //expire time in ms

var interval = 5000; //interval time in ms

setInterval(function() 
{
   var newTime = Date.now(),
   if (newTime - oldTime > interval+expire)
   {
      //call the expire function

   }
   oldTime = newTime
}, interval);
```